# Will temperature, pressure and volume effect the value of universal gas constant in any way?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

Effect of variables on constants:
Will temperature, pressure and volume effect the value of universal gas constant in any way?

Comment: It wouldn't be constant if they did...

Comment: I think it is a fair question.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at the gas constant, R, is the constant of proportionality between pressure x volume and particle count (n) x absolute temperature T. Thus, the well known ideal gas law: PV=nRT. But, and this gets to what I think might be your question, that's only for 'ideal' gases. For 'real' gasses, the gas law no longer applies. Changes in pressure, temperature, or number of particles can make a nearly ideal gas like Helium (for example) deviate from ideal gas law behavior. The description of this non-ideality is not handled by changing the value of R. Instead, the ideal gas law is not used and an approximation is used instead (e.g., the van der Walls equation, among others). The approximation is grounded in physics of course. They all attempt to handle finite particle sizes, particle interactions, etc. None of which occur in an 'ideal' gas.

R, by the way, is actually a 'compound' constant. It is defined by the product of Avagadro's number (N<sub>A</sub>) and Boltzman's constant k<sub>B</sub>. So R = N<sub>A</sub> x k<sub>B</sub>.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely...R does NOT change as you move from the ideal to the real world. That's the answer I was looking for. The specific heats at constant pressure and volume will change with temperature and since they are related algebraically to the gas constant, I was concerned that the gas constant would be temperature dependent. However, based on your information, the specific heats will change with high temperature but the in a coordinated way so that the gas constant .......stays constant.  Please confirm.